# A huge family of exception. A way to organize it

Tags: java

I have a huge family of exceptions:

```
class A extends Exception {}
class A1 extends A {}
class A2 extends A {}
...
class A40 extends A {}
```

No exception can be "repaired", but every exception must be displayed as error to user. Every exception (its type) carries another information so I cannot "reduce" number of exceptions. Because user must be notified, every thrown exception is "pulled" to the GUI.

It is problematic? Why? For example:

```
private void f() throws A1, A2, ..., A20 {}
```

A some solution (*) might be:

```
private void f() throws A {}
```

And, to "recover" type of exception:

```
void function_in_GUI(){
try {

} catch(A a){
    handle(a);
}

void handle(A a){
   try{
     throw a;
   } catch(A1 a){
     notify_user();
    } catch(A2 a){
    ....
     }
    ....

}

}
```

1. What do you think about (*)?
2. The cannonical way to do it is...

Comment: Anything common about these exceptions? Can they be  same Exception class with different attributes?

Comment: *"...another information so I cannot "reduce" number of exceptions"* - I seriously doubt the statement that it can not be reduced.

Comment: The canonical way is *not* to create a huge amount of exceptions. I've written less exceptions in 20 years than you've got in this single example.

Comment: What if you only had one exception class and each instance would contain one of the 40 error codes that you could model as an `enum`? The plaintext error messages could be included there too.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally in such a class hierarchy, you would have a base implementation of some method in class A and then that method being overridden in it subclasses A1, A2, ..., A40 with each subclass providing its own custom implementation for that method. If you have that kind of structure, it can be handled elegantly.

```
void function_in_GUI(){
   try {

   } catch(A a){
       SomeInfo someInfo = a.someMethod();
       notify_User(someInfo);
   }
}
```

The idea is that you don't have to catch each individual exception just to get some information from an exception that occurs at run time.

Comment: good answer. If exception handling is just to notify user, then there is no need to catch each exception separately. Maybe it is even not required to have so deep exception class hierarchy? ' each exception carries another information' but if this information is just for GUI, then maybe common structure (for GUI message) is everything you need?
You should always keep original exception as field. So root cause could be logged/debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Extending RuntimeException has many advantages here. You don´t have to declare or catch the execption everwhere, but only catch the RuntimeException in a single place to show the problem with the extra information to the user.